# how to make this query executable in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i got this mssql query...
but then i want to use it in mysql..
when i executed this query...it said that

**Error Code: 1109. Unknown table in MULTI DELETE**

from my reading..it maybe related with alias which im using in my query...
this is my mssql query..hope anyone can help..thank you..

```
Delete logDetail
from logDetail ld1
where 
-- Absent rows only 
ld1.L_Time = '00:00:00'
and ld1.L_Status = 'TIDAK HADIR'
--  And there must be a COMING or BACK row for the same card on the same day 
and exists (select 1 from logDetail ld2
 where ld2.L_Date = ld1.L_Date
and ld2.L_CardID = ld1.L_CardID
and ld2.L_Time > '00:00:00'
and ld2.L_Status <> 'TIDAK HADIR')
```

Comment: Which is it - your tag says MySQL and you text says MSSQL.

Comment: @Adrian: Read the first sentence again: got MSSQL, want MySQL.

Comment: Then it should be tagged with both

Comment: sorry for my mistake...pardon me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [mysql delete join syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) for a more efficient query:

```
delete ld1 from logDetail ld1
join logDetail ld2 on ld2.L_Date = ld1.L_Date -- Note join for efficient query
    and ld2.L_CardID = ld1.L_CardID
    and ld2.L_Time > '00:00:00'
    and ld2.L_Status <> 'TIDAK HADIR'
where ld1.L_Time = '00:00:00'
and ld1.L_Status = 'TIDAK HADIR'
```

I've 
moved all the ld2 conditions up into the `on` clause of the join.

This syntax avoids the `where exists ()` syntax which is very, very slow (one query *per row*!).

Comment: thank you very much @Bohemian...it's working like charm! god bless you!

Answer (score 2):

```
Delete logDetail
```

The mistake is probably there, the syntax to delete a record is:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

**Edit**
If you want to delete from `ld1` using the records from `ld2` in your condition your query should look something like:

```
DELETE FROM ld1
WHERE
ld1.L_Time = '00:00:00'
AND ld1.L_Status = 'TIDAK HADIR'
AND EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM ld2
     WHERE ld2.L_Date = ld1.L_Date
     AND ld2.L_CardID = ld1.L_CardID
     AND ld2.L_Time > '00:00:00'
     AND ld2.L_Status <> 'TIDAK HADIR');
```

### Don't copy paste this code in your console, I do not have your tables so I haven't tried it, analyse it and use it as a reference. I will not be liable if your whole DB implodes in a fiery inferno of dead and destruction

Comment: Isn't `FROM` optional? Also `ld1` and `ld2` are aliases - one on the table to delete, the other defined within the correlated subquery.

Comment: `FROM` Is not optional, look [DELETE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: @Triztian that very page shows this example, using an alias, which roughly matches the OP's code: `DELETE t1 FROM test AS t1, test2 WHERE ...` so I still think the conclusion that the syntax is incorrect because it doesn't say `DELETE FROM table` is wrong.